# How to sign out for clients with identityserver 4?

Tags: c#, single-sign-on, microservices, identityserver4

I am setting up identity server 4 for multiple clients. I want to implement single-sign-on for all clients. Whenever a user signs out from one client, the user is still signed in on other clients using the same identity server.

I have tried SignOutAsync("oidc") and SignOutAsync("Cookies") and tried deleting all cookies, but it doesn't help.

The following is the Logout method in all client applications:

```cs
public async Task Logout()
{
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("oidc");
    await HttpContext.SignOutAsync("Cookies");

    var myCookies = Request.Cookies.Keys;
    foreach (string cookie in myCookies)
    {
        Response.Cookies.Delete(cookie, new CookieOptions()
        {
            Domain = ".domain.com"
        });
    }
}
```

I want to sign out of all client applications but it only signs out of the application that initiates the sign out.

Comment: You can implement a [back channel logout](https://blog.tretainfotech.com/posts/2018/august/single-sign-out-in-identityserver4-with-back-channel-logout/). And the [documentation](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/signout.html#notifying-clients-that-the-user-has-signed-out).